# Hg update to previous commit removing any changes

Tags: mercurial

```
working directory
```

Did a

```
hg commit (resulted in rev3)
```

Copied some directories inside ... changed some files. Did

```
hg add  
hg commit (resulted in rev4 - tip)
```

How to get back exactly to the state of ***rev3***. `hg update 3` will change the files to the state they were in ***rev3***, but it will also leave all the copied directories inside. I want to get the working directory without the copied directories and files, which were added after rev3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't happen for me:

```
> hg init
> mkdir first
> jed first/foo.txt
> hg add
   adding first/foo.txt
> hg commit -m asd
> mkdir second
> jed second/foo.txt
> hg add
   adding second/foo.txt
> hg commit -m asd
> hg update 0
```

Now `first` exists, but `second` doesn't...

Are you sure you added everything in the new directories before your commit?

Comment: Could be ... don't know anymore, deleted it. But good to know that's not the expected behavior, so at least I'll know it's my error ... Just tried your example, so yes, that was probably the source of an error.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jon writes, Mercurial will normally try to clean up after itself. So when you `hg update` you should get back exactly what you committed. What I guess you're seeing is the following behavior:

```
$ hg init repo
$ cd repo
$ echo "# some C program" > foo.c
$ hg add foo.c
$ hg commit -m first
$ mkdir dir
$ echo "$ other C program" > dir/bar.c
$ hg add dir/bar.c
$ hg commit -m second
$ echo "object file" > dir/bar.o
$ hg update 0
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ ls
foo.c  dir
$ ls dir
bar.o
```

So the untracked `dir/bar.o` file has been left behind, but the tracked `dir/bar.c` file has been correctly removed. That is: Mercurial **wont delete untracked files** since it doesn't know if they contain valuable data. This applies even if the files are ignored by a pattern in `.hgignore`. If the directory had only contained the tracked `dir/bar.c` file, then the directory would have been completely removed when you update to a revision where it isn't needed.

The normal way to clean up untracked files is to use the [purge extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension).